# How to disable the OpenVPN Web UI and keep tunnelling feature

Tags: openvpn

I installed OpenVPN server according to DigitalOcean's manual (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-openvpn-access-server-on-ubuntu-12-04).

I prepared all that I need and VPN works fine. Now I do not want the Web UI any more. Is there a way to disable it (I want to install nginx for both HTTP and HTTPS) and keep tunnelling?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can't actually disable it because the client connection relies on it. However, you can set it to localhost only, so it refuses all external connections except for openvpn clients.

```
/usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts/sacli -k admin_ui.https.ip_address -v localhost configput
/usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts/sacli -k cs.https.ip_address -v localhost configput
/usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts/sacli start
```

the value "-v" you can use 'localhost' even '127.0.0.1'(for other tunnels) or server's  public ip and interface name like 'eth2'

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using OpenVPN Access Server, which is a commercial product from OpenVPN Technologies (the company of the original author). If you're willing to pay, you could contact them for support. Otherwise, you probably want the community version of OpenVPN.

This wiki page has up-to-date information on how to use the available repositories:
https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenvpnSoftwareRepos

Once you've installed the community version, figure out where your OpenVPN AS config files and server keys are (I guess in /etc/openvpn-as, but I never actually ran AS, so I'm not sure), and copy them over to /etc/openvpn. AS is a set of tooling around the community edition for easy administration, so the config files should just work with the community edition.